# getting hidden values in drop down list

Tags: html, angularjs, tags, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I am using drop down which should display list in my object using ng-option.
I am getting list of four items in drop down,I am not able to see items in drop down

```
 <select class="" ng-model="vendor.termMaster.termTypeMaster.id" ng-options="t.id as t.terms for t in fetchTermTypeList">
                                                            <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
```

above is html code sample what I have done.

```
    $scope.fetchTermType= function(){

        vendorsList_Service.fetchTermType().then(function(response){

            $scope.fetchTermTypeList=response.data;
            console.log($scope.fetchTermTypeList);

            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        },function(response){
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        }); 
    };
```

$scope.fetchTermType();

This is my controller

Comment: Can you also include your code where you are creating the `np-option`.  So far all we can tell from your code is you hit a service to get some data back and then put that data in a list and log it and fade out a loader.  There's not really a god way of telling what you are going after to put the data in the list anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for response, yeah I edited you can  make look over it and I am getting data back by my method.

Comment: Is the JavaScript code you posted in the loading method in the controller?  I'm a bit confused about why you have everything wrapped up in a function.  Logic would dictate, and I can't be sure because I'm not looking at your app obviously, that this `fetchTermType` function is never being called, hence the data isn't be populated.

Comment: yeaha actually it is angularJS controller not java script.  fetchTermType method is a self called method when ever page get refreshed, it will be called  automatically.I called method after method completion.